# Spring security login https with tomcat in Amazon EC2 not working

Tags: tomcat, https, amazon-ec2, spring-security

I am trying to set up https login for my application. In my local Ubuntu environment it is working fine, however when I deploy everything to Amazon EC2 Ubuntu, I cannot get it working.

The following is what I did:

1 . generate keystore using:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /etc/tomcat6/keystore
```

2 . Modify tomcat server.xml file to include:

```
     <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
                       connectionTimeout="20000" 
                       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                       redirectPort="8443" />    

     <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
            maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
            keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat6/keystore" 
            keystorePass="tomcat"/>
```

3 . Modified my spring xml file to include:

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="delegatingAEP">
    ...
    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    </port-mappings>

    ...

    <intercept-url pattern="/login"                   access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    ...
 </http>
```

4 . For my Amazon EC2 instance, I opened HTTPS port 8443 in EC2 security group. My local Ubuntu instance don't need to.

5 . Restarted Tomcat. When I try to access http://www.mysite.com:8080/ in Amazon EC2, it is redirected to https://www.mysite.com:8443/login successfully, however with content "This webpage is not available".

The same configuration is working fine in my local Ubuntu. Both my local and my Amazon Ec2 server are running on Ubuntu 11.10.

Where might go wrong in my configuration?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by creating new Amazon EC2 security group with HTTPS port 443/8443 opened first, then launch new Amazon EC2 instance with that newly created security group.

It seemed that if you create Amazon EC2 security group without HTTPS port 443/8443, and then assigned it to an instance. Afterward you change that security group to include HTTPS port 443/8443, the HTTPS port does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my app using Https, I wanna redirect port of Tomcat from 443 to 8443.

fincally this works for me:

## /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

## /sbin/service iptables save